# Prove $X \not\approx \boldsymbol{2}^{X}$ using contradiction

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am proving the theorem $X \not\approx \boldsymbol{2}^{X}$. It is required that contradiction be used in the proof. My thought is presented below.

We can assume there is a function $f: X \to \boldsymbol{2}^{X}$. Intuitively, we understand that $X$ has to be "smaller" than $\boldsymbol{2}^{X}$. So if $f$ is one-one, it cannot be onto. So we should assume the function is one-one and try to argue that it is not onto. The condition of being one-one gives me the following argument:

Since $f$ is one-one, if $x_{1}, x_{2} \in X$ and $x_{1} \neq x_{2}$, then $f\left(x_{1}\right) \neq f\left(x_{2}\right)$. Then without loss of generality, there exists $y \in X$ such that $\left[f\left(x_{1}\right)\right]\left(y\right) = \boldsymbol{0}$ and $\left[f\left(x_{2}\right)\right]\left(y\right) = \boldsymbol{1}$.

I guess I have fully utilized the condition of $f$ being one-one. But how can I construct a contradiction assuming that $f$ is also onto?

Answer (score 2):

Theorem: If X is a set, then X is not equivalent to its power set.

Proof: Suppose for a contradiction that $f:X\to P(X)$ is a bijection. Define $B:=\{x \in X| x\not\in f(x)\}$. Because $f$ is surjective (onto), there is an element $g$ in $X$ with $B=f(g)$.

Since $B$ is a subset of $X$ and $g$ is an element of $X$, it has to be that either $g\in B$ or $g\not\in B$.

If $g\in B$, then $g\in f(g)$. Then by definition of $B$, $g\not\in B$. So this can't be.

If $g\not\in B$, then $g\not\in f(g)$. Then by definition of $B$, $g\in B$. Again, this cannot be.
So it is impossible that there is some $g\in X$ such that $f(g)=\{x\in X∣x\not\in f(x)\}$.

Comment: @ZiqiFan Can't use what theorem? I haven't *used* a theorem, I've *proven* a theorem.

Comment: I guess you are saying $X \not\approx \mathscr{P}\left(X\right)$, and using the fact that $\mathscr{P}\left(X\right) \approx \boldsymbol{2}^{X}$ to show $X \not\approx \boldsymbol{2}^{X}$. Is there a way to prove it directly?

Comment: Probably, but this proof, plus the line that isomorphism is an equivalence relation, is as much as I'd say you'd need to put for any question.

Comment: @Ziqi: Just replace the $x\in f(x)$ with $f(x)=1$, and $x\notin f(x)$ with $f(x)=0$. Also, this proof is not *really* using a contradiction. It's a direct proof that if $f$ is any function, then it is not surjective.